# Same page doesn't read a cookie from mobile but works well in pc web browser

Tags: php, cookies

I have a php page which reads cookies from browser. Thing is it reads cookies well from laptop browser, however fails to read from mobile browser.

Please be noted, I've already checked whether cookies are getting saved through debugging.

Code is like this:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnect.php';
include 'verify_cookie.php';
if($userid){
    echo 'Logged in';
}
else{
    echo 'Not logged in';
}
?>
```

**VERIFY COOKIE**

```
<?php
session_start();
  if(isset($_COOKIE['exp_id'])){
    $userid=$_COOKIE['emp_id'];
  }
?>
```

It says Logged in in a PC web browser, says Not logged in in mobile browser. I'm using Chrome 46.0.2490.76 build on my mobile & haven't checked in other browsers yet. Can somebody help in this?

Comment: Did you mean for the line `$userid=$_COOKIE['emp_id'];` to be `$userid=$_COOKIE['exp_id'];` ?

Comment: Yeah the same, however I just tried with other device & it seems to be working. I think there is issue with something else other than my code. Thank you, closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with something else other than my code, it worked in other device I tried.
I will dig out further in that.